# Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop)

Tags: r, dplyr, latex, knitr

I have a question for you please.

I use knitr (latex) in R. This code : 
`Check <- as.data.frame(data %>% group_by(CITY) %>% summarise(NumberSizeCity = n_distinct(SURFACE), SURFACE = list(unique(SURFACE))))` work in R. I want to know if there is only one size for one city. But when I compile (PDF) my work, I have the error message : Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop)... Do you have any idea please ? (City : unique code, and SURFACE is numeric).

Thank you !

Comment: Do you have a sample of what `data` looks like? It should have at least `CITY` and `SURFACE`.

Comment: `YEAR<- c(2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006,2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006)` ;  `CITY <- c(7113, 7232, 7232, 7033 ,7211 ,7279 ,7279 ,7279 ,7058 ,7107 ,7107 ,7024 ,7024 ,7024 ,7024 ,7024, 7024 ,7024 ,7150 ,7040, 7349 ,7221 ,7178 ,7219 ,7204 ,7087 ,7167 ,7299 ,7065` ; `SURFACE <- c(2313.16, 5600 ,5087.09 , 1727.17 ,2021.91 ,3340 ,3345 ,3340 ,1238.97 2444.44, 2444.44 ,3284, 3284 ,3284 ,3284 ,3284 ,3284 ,3284 ,1639.52, 883.95, 989 1601.03 ,482.17 706.33 ,4845.2 ,757.66 ,739, 1950.19, 695.33)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code counts the number of distinct `SURFACE`s associated with each unique `CITY`:

```
library(dplyr)

CITY <- c(
  7113, 7232, 7232, 7033, 7211, 7279, 7279, 7279, 7058, 7107, 
  7107, 7024, 7024, 7024, 7024, 7024, 7024, 7024, 7150, 7040, 
  7349, 7221, 7178, 7219, 7204, 7087, 7167, 7299, 7065
)
SURFACE <- c(
  2313.16, 5600, 5087.09, 1727.17, 2021.91, 3340, 3345, 3340, 
  1238.97, 2444.44, 2444.44, 3284, 3284, 3284, 3284, 3284, 
  3284, 3284, 1639.52, 883.95, 989, 1601.03, 482.17, 706.33, 
  4845.2, 757.66, 739, 1950.19, 695.33
)

data <- data.frame(
  CITY = CITY,
  SURFACE = SURFACE
)

Check <- data %>% group_by(
  CITY
) %>% count(
  SURFACE
) %>% ungroup() %>% count(
  CITY # nn
)

Check
#   CITY    nn
#   7024    1
#   7033    1
#   7040    1
#   7058    1
#   7065    1
#   7087    1
#   7107    1
#   7113    1
#   7150    1
#   7167    1
#   7178    1
#   7204    1
#   7211    1
#   7219    1
#   7221    1
#   7232    2
#   7279    2
#   7299    1
#   7349    1
```